# && operator in JSONpath ()

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

Below is the sample json from the [tutorial](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath)

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

I am trying to check for the objects with the following condition

```
$..[?(@.price == 12.99 && @.title == 'Moby Dick')]
```

which should have retrivd me as shown below. But, it only shows [].

```
{
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
```

Any pointers as to where in the query is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `||` instead of `&&`, since you want objects with either price (not both, which is impossible):

```
$..[?(@.price == 12.99 || @.price == 8.99)]
```

Comment: I am trying to build a IF-THEN statement. wherein, do something IF both of them are there?

Comment: My answer produces thec results your question  said you wanted. Are you trying to ask a different question? If so, please open a new question.

Comment: May be I was not clear the first time. I have modified the query now. Can you see how I could change the query in such a situation.

Comment: You would still use `||` in that case, since it would still be an OR condition. Also, if you change your question in such a way as to make existing  answers no longer make sense, you should put something like `[UPDATED]` in the question.

Comment: Thanks. I missed the [UPDATED] thing

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood how work the && operator. If I understand what you want, you search the object (with all fields in) where the field "price" is equal to 12.99 "and" the object (with all fields in) where the field "title" is equal to Moby Dick.

But when you type `$..[?(@.price == 12.99 && @.title == 'Moby Dick')]`, you search each object where one of its fields named "price" is equal to 12.99 and in this same object another field named "title" is equal to Moby Dick.

And none of this objects has this two conditions satisfied. So the answer is [] (no object found or no match)

To get the correct result, you don't search this object with and this object with but the object(s) with this field equals to OR (|| operator) the object(s) with this other field equals to.

So the answer of cybersam is the correct answer programmatically

I hope this is clear and helps